# CruiseControl access restriction: how?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol, phpundercontrol

I am currently testing [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net) + [phpUnderControl](http://phpundercontrol.org/) for our PHP CI process and am stuck with a fairly simple question: is it possible to somehow restrict access to the web interface?

I cannot seem to find anything indicating this is possible, but I am probably overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't Apache's mod_auth work?

Why don't you use mod_proxy ot redirect cruisecontrol's web interface through apache? then use apache auth.  At phpexperts.pro, i have cruisecontrol listening on localhost:8080 and then i use mod_proxy like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpexperts.pro

    <Location "/cruisecontrol/">
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        Satisfy any
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from 127.0.0.1

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "private"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/phpexperts.pro/.htpasswd
        AuthGroupFile /dev/null
        Require valid-user


        # Pass in CruiseControl's web interface.
        ProxyPass  http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So far I haven't found a way to run CruiseControl from Apache